# Как записать верхний индекс при работе с excel (библиотека excel4node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

На nodeJS делаю запись в excel-файл при помощи библиотеки [excel4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node), может кто сталкивался.

Как при записи в ячейку писать верхний индекс (`м^2` и т.д.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

excel таки наверно поддерживает utf-8, в общем индекс это обычный символ

```
    'x\u00B0' //x°
    'x\u00B2' //x²
    'x\u00B3' //x³
    'x\u00B2' === 'x²' //true
```

upd

```
    'x\u207B\u00B2' //x⁻²
```

Comment: @388752,а если в степени минус?

Comment: ````"x\u207B\u00B2" //x⁻²````